# Link Vertical Data to Horizontal Data

Tags: excel

I've got a load of data in Sheet2 that goes down vertical in Column C.  On Sheet1 I would like to put the horizontally.
ie.

**Sheet 2**

```
C1 = A 
C2 = B 
C3 = C
```

**Sheet1**

```
E20 = A
F20 = B
G20 = C
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?
I tried =TRANSPOSE(Overview!$C:$C) but no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracked it :)

=INDEX(**RANGE OF VERTICAL DATA**,COLUMNS($A:A))
=INDEX(Overview!$C3:$C1000,COLUMNS($E:E))

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to copy the data more than once?

If not, then you can use the Paste Special -feature and check the transpose checkbox.

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/transpose.php

How didn't the function-version of transpose work?